# How to implement Android splash screen using svg instead of png?

Tags: android, svg, react-native

I make RN app. For Android version I have made
/drawable/splash_screen.xml with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

  <item>
    <bitmap
      android:gravity="center"
      android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

and links to this file in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

also in AndoirdManifest.xml

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

This works fine, but I'd like to make SVG file instead PNG (mipmap/ic_launcher).
The SVG file might be like this
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html
(at least without animation).
How to achieve this?

Comment: I tryed with a scale drawable, but its default level is 0 and can not be set in the drawable xml. That's a shame because it would be the solution. <scale 
       android:drawable="@drawable/somesvg"
       android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
       android:scaleHeight="100%"
       android:scaleWidth="80%" />

Answer (score 29):

The default SVG importer in the Android Studio doesn't work too well, so I recommend to use a SVG to VectorDrawable converter like [svg2android](https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/).

Now we need to create a drawable file using the code generated by the svg2android.

> **res/drawable** --> new --> drawable resource file --> paste the vector code there

And on the `splash_screen.xml` we need to add an item using our vector 
as `drawable` with a `gravity` set to `center`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- background with solid color -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

    <!-- logo -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/your_logo"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</layer-list>
```

-- Edited (Dec 2019) --

As @petyr pointed in the comments, the svg2android is now deprecated, but the as @Krisztián suggested, the [Respresso Image Converter](https://respresso.io/image-converter) can do virtually everything that svg2android can.
Just add a SVG image into it, leave it in `auto` and it will produce an Android compatible SVG.

Comment: the tool svg2android has been deprecated though

Comment: You can try [Respresso's image converter](https://respresso.io/image-converter). It is maintained and works better than the Android Studio. It can handle different API level features (eg.: gradients).

Comment: @KrisztiánVelez but this Respresso image converter doesn't have the same capability:   not compatible SVG > to > android compatible SVG. That was the magic of svg2android.

Comment: @petyr You can use the built in vector asset from Android Studio or still use the svg2android. If anyone have a better alternative for that, I'll edit the post and add it :)

Comment: @NícolasSchirmer I worked with the Respresso team. As I know they compared the the capabilities of these tools. All features of svg2android were implemented. I am sure that if you send a few samples which are not working to info@respresso.io they will appreciate it.

Comment: @KrisztiánVelez That is very cool, thank you, I'll be in touch with them to see if there is any possibility to get an output to Android compatible SVG like svg2android, because in the mean time there is only png, jpeg and webp outputs. The SVG output is good because using a vector as an image helps with performance, memory usage, bundle size and compatibility issues.

Comment: @NícolasSchirmer Try to use the `auto` option. It will produce vector images when possible. If you upload an svg it will return an Android Drawable. It's called `auto` to let it choose the best option for you depending on your uploaded image (svg, png, jpeg, pdf, android drawable). Any other option is an enforcement if you need a specific format. Android Drawable is not listed as it can not be produced from a png image so it can not be enforced.

Comment: @KrisztiánVelez You are absolutely right, I did not had tested that, only assumed that it was not there. Thank you for your indication. :)

Comment: 2021 Represso no longer provides SVG conversion for Android

Answer (score 7):

In the xml file you need to use the attribute drawable only instead of a bitmap tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>

  <item android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: so I need to put my SVG into each mipmap-Xdpi folder?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can use the Asset Import Tool to import one SVG file

Comment: thank you, i had been exploring internet and didn't work until i got this answer

Answer (score 1):

First conversion to xml and second naming of managed elements in svg. (VectorDrawable) android_svg.xml:

```
   <vector android:height="400dp" android:viewportHeight="206.132".....>
   ...............
    <path android:name = "arrow"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M 47.30268,56.147897 37.688314,45.379807"
        android:strokeAlpha="1" android:strokeColor="#151414"
        android:strokeLineCap="butt" android:strokeLineJoin="miter" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
   </vector>
```

Third use of AnimatedVectorDrawable to animate VectorDrawable:

```
 <animated-vector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        ............................>
    <target android:name="arrow">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set android:ordering="sequentially">
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:valueFrom="M 47.30268,56.147897 37.688314,45.379807"
                    android:valueTo=  "M 47.30268,56.147897 37.688314,45.379807"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="1000"
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:valueFrom="M 47.30268,56.147897 37.688314,45.379807"
                    android:valueTo=  "M 47.30268,56.147897 57.686195,45.187519"
                    android:valueType="pathType"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
            </set>

        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

Here is https://www.ap-impulse.com/animaciya-svg-dlya-web-i-android-splash-screen-shag-105/ for a description of how to use the above.
Here's the project itself https://github.com/nik137/Diagnostics

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

Hi you can simply import your svg into your project by following this :

1. Right Click on drawable folder in android studio.
2. Choose New > Vector Drawable > Local File
3. After importing file will copied to drawable folder.
4. Now you can reference drawable like this

   ```
   <item
       android:drawable="@color/off_white"/>

   <item>
       <bitmap
           android:gravity="center"
           android:src="@drawable/yoursvg"/>
   </item>
   ```

After this you should be able to see you image on screen. Please test and accept it as answer if it helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this not works. App crashes at startup (popup message: "Myapp has stopped"). I have tried with svg from AnimatedVectorDrawable and my svg file.

Comment: On which device you are testing if it is lower than lolipop than you should add this line to you build.gradle file   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Comment: I use Android 5.0+

Comment: A vector is not a bitmap. Thus it won't load in the bitmap tag.

Comment: This does not work, the drawable folder cannot contain svg files, only xml and png